# numpy: How do you "break" a numpy operation?

Tags: numpy

I accidentally tried to make a 200,000 x 200,000 array in numpy.  Control-C does not seem to break the operation.  Is there any way to stop the array creation *without* simply killing the python session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is that numpy has large portions written in C.

When Python begins executing a compiled function, the Python signal handling is effectively paused until the execution of the compiled code is finished.

This is bad news for your interactive Python session, but there isn't much you can do aside from waiting for the inevitable OutOfMemoryError, or killing the session.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately no.  Python (and MatLab, the only other analysis package I use) do not detect the user interrupt until the current operation (NOT run) is finished.